# Execute closure from another method in an extension Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, closures

I have a class that is a delegate to a custom modal view, therefore it has a method for when the modal has been dismissed. I am extending that class and in the extension I have a method that accepts a completion closure.

I can't write in the main implementation of the class or the modal's implementation - only the extension.

I want to execute the closure when the modal is dismissed, but I can't seem to figure it out on my own. Is it even possible?

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
extension MyClass {
    func method(completion: (Int) -> ()) {
        // showing the modal
    }
}

extension MyClass: ModalDelegate {
    func modalDismissed() {
        // here I want to execute the completion passed to method()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible if you can't write in `MyClass`. Why can't you write in `MyClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the completion as a variable to a `MyClass`'s property in `method` and call it in `modalDismissed`:

```swift
class MyClass {
    var classCompletion: (() -> ())?
}

extension MyClass {
    func method(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        classCompletion = completion
    }
}

extension MyClass: ModalDelegate {
    func modalDismissed() {
        classCompletion?()
    }
}
```

Update: If you can't "write in the main implementation of the class", here's a method using `static` property. This is a hack and has many limitations but does the work. Otherwise without writing to the main implementation you can't do anything.

```swift
extension MyClass {
    static var classCompletion: (() -> ())?

    func method(completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        MyClass.classCompletion = completion
    }
}

extension MyClass: ModalDelegate {
    func modalDismissed() {
        MyClass.classCompletion?()
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can't write in the main implementation of the class" though. Adding a property would require doing that...

Comment: @Sweeper Oh, thanks for bringing my attention to that.